# Daily totals, by tag

Tags: emacs, report, org-mode

I've recently started using org-mode (and Emacs in general) and I love the time tracking elements. It is probably the first solution that accurately represents what had previously worked for me in my paper based system.

I'm not overly familiar with the reporting capabilities so this question is more one for guidance:

**Is it possible to produce a report for a given week, that totals up the time spent on tags for each day?**

For instance:

```
Monday
2 hrs :support:
3 hrs :support:
1 hr  :meetings:
```

And from there produce me a table that would have the totals for Monday, Tuesday, etc:

```
Monday
Total :support: 5 hrs
Total :meetings: 1hr
```

The format is not relevant, more so just the ability to automate what I currently have to do manually - add up the tags, per day and log in a time-sheeting application.

Please keep in mind I'm still learning so if I come up with a solution myself, I'll include it here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you've not got there yourself yet, what you're looking for is *clock tables* in org-mode. See [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) for details.

There are a great many ways of filtering and breaking down the information presented. As an example, I use the following clock table to get a report of what I did *last* week broken down by day; I then use this when filling in my timesheet.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :scope agenda-with-archives :block lastweek :step day :fileskip0 :formatter :link 2 :indent t :narrow 79 :formula % :tags "-NOCLOCK"
#+END:
```

This is reasonably self-explanatory if you read that link to the org-mode manual. The `-NOCLOCK` tag filter allows me to mark some tasks such that they never appear in the report. I use this for 'lunch', for example.

Once you're written this clock table specification just put the point in it and press <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.

This then gives you a clock table looking like the following (only Monday is shown in this example, and with a very limited set of test data for that report, but you get the idea):

```
Daily report: [2014-11-24 Mon]
 File        Headline                                                                Time              % 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             ALL *Total time*                                                      *0:25*          100.0 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 agenda.org  *File time*                                                           *0:14*           56.0 
             [Org-mode maintenance]                                                  0:14           56.0 
               [STARTED {#B} Weekly review]                                                0:14     56.0 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 work.org    *File time*                                                           *0:11*           44.0 
             [Default task to soak up time when not clocked into a specific task]    0:11           44.0 
               [STARTED Non-specific work activity]                                        0:11     44.0
```

The time is nicely broken down as per the task breakdown, summarised at each level.

You asked about doing this for tags; you could use the `tags` filter parameter on the clock table definition to achieve that, either summarising them into the same table, or having separate tables for each tag.

Comment: This works and makes sense. As you say, one can have a separate table for each tag. Is there a way to have *one* table, which identifies time by tag?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot automatically summarise by tag. You can add ":properties ("TAGS") :inherit-props t" to the table spec to show tags for each entry, but it's still broken down by task rather than tag, unfortunately.